# LNNVL to replace NOT IN?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

This one was a bit difficult to search, so I'm asking here (where I saw questions regarding `lnnvl()`).

I have a query that looks like:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE foo.bar NOT IN ('X', 'Y')
   OR foo.bar IS NULL;
```

Moments ago I learned about `lnnvl()` and I was able to do the same thing with:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE lnnvl(foo.bar = 'X')
  AND lnnvl(foo.bar = 'Y');
```

That is fantastic, but not very scalable when checking a larger set. Is there a cleaner way that any of you folks know of? In the past, I've done something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE nvl(foo.bar, ' ') NOT IN ('X', 'Y')
```

I appreciate any insights!

Comment: What is wrong with your *existing* query? It is very clear, scalable, and efficient - why do you need something different? LNNVL has other, legitimate uses.

Comment: The first one seems to run slower than the third in my practical tests, and the `lnnvl(<...>)` logic looks like it could still take advantage of an index (but I didn't see a noticeable difference in performance). I want to make sure I'm not missing something obvious due to my (relative) inexperience, like if there was a way to essentially perform `lnnvl(foo.bar NOT IN ('X', 'Y'))`.

The reality is, we rarely have to check a collection of more than 3 constants, but I want to do this the "right" way before I get too comfortable with bad techniques.

Comment: Check the execution plans, I doubt that the third query can possibly out-perform the first query.

Comment: No any null-handling function can take advantage of the (plain, not function-based) index, because nulls are not indexed at all, so Oracle has no way to read rows with `null` using index. Also in general index is not used for `not in` predicate, because it means *everything except few cases*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last option is fine and leads to following `filter`predicate

```
filter(NVL("FOO"."BAR",' ')<>'X' AND NVL("FOO"."BAR",' ')<>'Y')
```

I do not see other possibility as the predicate below leads to an exception

```
WHERE lnnvl(foo.bar IN ('X', 'Y')); 
ORA-13207: incorrect use of the [LNNVL] operator
```

If your table is *very* large and you want to avoid *full table scan* you may even define a *function based index* as

```
create index idx on foo(nvl(bar,' '));
```

This will *prevent* the *full table scan*, but unfortunately the index can't be used as usual - as you check for the *inequity* `<>`.

So the result is a *full index scan* i.e. you go through the *whole* index and filter the *not matching keys*, accesing the table only for the right keys.

This could be meaningfull if the table is large and the result set is small.

**Execution Plan**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |      |   250 |   489K|   269   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| FOO  |   250 |   489K|   269   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX FULL SCAN                   | IDX  |   250 |       |   185   (2)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - filter(NVL("BAR",' ')<>'X' AND NVL("BAR",' ')<>'Y')
```

**BTW**

you can't use index for the predicate `lnnvl(bar = 'X')` which leads obvious to *full table scan* with the predicate `filter(LNNVL("BAR"='X'))`

Anyway you may re-formulate the predicate to

```
WHERE 
case when lnnvl(bar = 'X') then 1 end = 1
```

and define `FBI` index

```
create index idx2 on foo( case when lnnvl(bar = 'X') then 1 end );
```

which leads to a *nice*  `index range scan`

you may even use `and` e.g.

```
where case when lnnvl(bar = 'X') and lnnvl(bar = 'Y') then 1 end = 1
```

Comment: I don't "own" the tables so I won't be creating an index on it, but there is an existing index on `bar`. I don't really know enough, but maybe you do-- would `lnnvl(bar = 'X')` be able to take advantage of that existing index, since the function is applied after the comparison?

Comment: @zeda updated additional info